# How can I make is_pod<T> tests be performed during compilation and not execution?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

This might be an easy question, I don't master C++11 templates at all.

I have a generic vector class that is not `std::vector<T>` for performance reasons (very specific code).

I have observed that checking whether `T` is a POD or not and, when it is, perform special computations, is much more efficient than not :

```
void vec<T>::clear() {
  if (!std::is_pod<T>::value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       data[i].~T();
    }
  }

  size = 0;
}
```

Here, I don't call the destructor of `T` for each item (`size` can be really huge) and performance is really boosted. But the test `if (!std::is_pod<T>::value)` is useless once the template was compiled : rather than being compiled to :

```
void vec<int>::clear() {
  if (false) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       data[i].~int();
    }
  }

  size = 0;
}
```

I want it to be compiled to :

```
void vec<int>::clear() {
  size = 0;
}
```

Is the compiler "clever" enough to skip `if (false)` blocks or `if (true)` tests ? Do I have to write that code somewhat differently ?

Comment: I'm really surprised if the compiler doesn't know to automatically eliminate the whole loop as a no-op when T is a pod. Are you sure you had optimization enabled when testing?

Comment: At least with GCC on any optimization level other than -O0, the loop is completely gone from the resulting ASM, without any explicit checking. Plus, the compiler can and does optimize out the destructor calls even if the type is not strictly a POD if it can otherwise prove they aren't needed.

Comment: Try it!  Learn how to get your compiler to output assembly code, and look at that generated code.  I suggest you look at the unoptimized assembly code first, so you can see how it relates to your source code, then start to look at the optimized assembly code.  You can compare what (if anything) changes when you completely delete that loop.

Comment: Actually, that's not the only occurrence of `is_pod` in my code, only the most obvious. I have, among other things, loops that are translated to `memcpy`, not just empty blocks. So the generated output is not the same every time.

Comment: @Fabien: Yes, even the crappiest C++ compiler will eliminate it.  If you don't believe us then simply decompile.  `objdump -d` (or your platforms equivalent) is your friend.

Comment: Using `int` for size is a terrible idea.

Comment: Please use `is_trivially_destructible` rather than `is_pod`. POD is a *lot* more strict than merely trivially destructible.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Is the compiler "clever" enough to skip if (false) blocks or if (true) tests?

Yes, definitely. [Dead code elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination) is a trivial optimisation that is performed routinely. Its existence is also crucial to make many debugging libraries work efficiently (= without runtime overhead in release mode).

But I would probably still rewrite this to make it *visible to the reader* that this is a compile-time distinction, by overloading the function based on `is_pod`:

```
void vec<T>::do_clear(std::true_type) { }

void vec<T>::do_clear(std::false_type) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       data[i].~T();
    }
}

void vec<T>::clear() {
    do_clear(std::is_trivially_destructible<T>());
    size = 0;
}
```

In the above code I’m using [`is_trivially_destructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_destructible) instead of `is_pod` to make the code more self-explanatory, as suggested by Nicol in the comments. This technique is commonly employed in standard library implementations and other libraries. It’s known as [*tag dispatching*](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching).

Comment: This technique is called "tag-dispatching", btw.

Comment: Also, please do it on `is_trivially_destructible` rather than `is_pod`, so that it's clear *why* it's happening.

Answer (score 10):

There is a language feature called *pseudo destructors* which is specifically designed for what you want to do.  Basically given a type template parameter T you can syntactically call a destructor for it, and if, when instantiated, T is a scalar type (because for example it is a fundamental type like an `int`) it will compile and generate a no-op in its place.

For the remainder of POD types that are not scalar, they have trivial destructors, so will likewise generate a no-op.

Any production compiler on even the lowest optimization setting will elide a loop over a no-op.  So you can safely write:

```
void vec<T>::clear() { 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       data[i].~T();
    }

    size = 0;
}
```

Basically, you are trying to solve an imaginary performance problem the compiler is already taking care of for you.

Comment: @Xeo: "Pseudo destructor call" is specified in section 5.2.4 of the C++ standard which is named (you guessed it) "Pseudo destructor call".  So I am suprised they have named a section of the C++ standard after a non-existent concept. ;)

Comment: Well, TIL. OP's code is still valid, so I'm kinda wondering what's the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Dead code elimination is a common optimization.

However, if you do not trust your compiler to do any optimization at all, you could create a static if `template` library.

Skip down to the punchline if you don't feel like reading a bunch of pretty horrible hacks.

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<bool b>
struct static_if_t {
  static_if_t( static_if_t const& ) = default;
  static_if_t() = default;
  static_if_t( static_if_t<b>(*)(std::integral_constant<bool,b>) ) {}
};

template<bool dead>
struct static_if_branch {};

template<bool b>
struct static_else_if_t {
  static_else_if_t( static_else_if_t const& ) = default;
  static_else_if_t() = default;
  static_else_if_t( static_else_if_t<b>(*)(std::integral_constant<bool,b>) ) {}
};

template<bool b>
static_if_t<b> static_if(std::integral_constant<bool,b> unused=std::integral_constant<bool,b>()) {return {};}
template<bool b>
static_else_if_t<b> static_else_if(std::integral_constant<bool,b> unused=std::integral_constant<bool,b>()) {return {};}

static auto static_else = static_else_if<true>;

template<typename Lambda, typename=typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< decltype(std::declval<Lambda&&>()()), decltype(std::declval<Lambda&&>()()) >::value >::type>
static_if_branch<true> operator*( static_if_t<true>, Lambda&& closure )
{
  std::forward<Lambda>(closure)();
  return {};
}
template<typename Lambda, typename=typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< decltype(std::declval<Lambda&&>()()), decltype(std::declval<Lambda&&>()()) >::value >::type>
static_if_branch<false> operator*( static_if_t<false>, Lambda&& /*closure*/ )
{
  return {};
}

template<typename Unused>
static_if_branch<true> operator*( static_if_branch<true>, Unused&& ) {
  return {};
}

static_if_t< true > operator*( static_if_branch<false>, static_else_if_t<true> ) {
  return {};
}
static_if_t< false > operator*( static_if_branch<false>, static_else_if_t<false> ) {
  return {};
}
```

And here is the punchline:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  static_if<true>* [&]{
    std::cout << "hello\n";
  } *static_else* [&]{
    std::cout << "doom\n";
  };

  static_if<false>* [&]{
    std::cout << "doom the\n";
  } *static_else* [&]{
    std::cout << "world\n";
  };

  static_if<false>* [&]{
    std::cout << "fello\n";
  } *static_else_if<false>* [&]{
    std::cout << "yellow\n";
  } *static_else_if<false>* [&]{
    std::cout << "hehe\n";
  };

  static_if( std::is_same<int, int>() )* [&]{
    std::cout << "int is int\n";
  };
  static_if( std::is_same<double, double>() )* [&]{
    std::cout << "double is double\n";
  } *static_else_if( std::is_same<int, double>() )* [&]{
    std::cout << "int is double\n";
  } *static_else* [&]{
    std::cout << "sky is not blue\n";
  };
}
```

but why would you want to do that?  [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=130e0beeef4afc9ffdc15adb9b404417-c59112800dca6ae4674520521ddfe536)

(note that there are two syntaxes the above `static_if` -- one `static_if<compile time boolean expression>`, and another `static_if( std::is_whatever<blah>() )`).

Now, while the above is completely insane, the above technique would let you write a compile time trinary operator that allows a different type based on which branch is picked.  Which is neat.

Ie, something like this:

```
auto result = trinary<std::is_same<A,B>::value>% 7 | 3.14;
```

and the type of `result` would be `int` if `A` and `B` are the same type, and `double` if they differ.  Or even:

```
auto result = meta_trinary<std::is_same<A,B>::value>% [&]{return 7;} | [&]{return 3.14;};
```

if you prefer, allowing entire blocks of code to be conditionally evaluated, and the conditional type of the return value to be stored.

Comment: Your answer already acknowledges that the only way this is useful, is if a compiler is so completely brain-dead that it cannot optimise away blocks skipped by constant conditionals. With such a brain-dead compiler, what do you imagine the effect of all these extra function calls will be? On realistic implementations, sure, this will run just fine, but no better than the code in the question, and in that case, the code in the question still wins for being significantly more readable.

Comment: @hvd Pretty much: the `static_if` is a joke.   In theory a compiler without the ability to notice static `if` clauses, but with inline support and the ability eliminate other dead code, could be helped by the above.  The syntax is pretty though!  (the things required to get that pretty syntax are pretty evil)  After I wrote it, I noticed that I could return a type from it that would differ based on which branch I took: that footnote about `static_trinary` could actually lead somewhere.

Comment: Sure, but you can already achieve that with a helper class that has two functions with different return types, and pass that local class as a template argument to something that statically resolves to calling one function or the other. I do admit that what you came up with, as hard to read as it is, *does* look pretty to me too though. :)