# conditional template based code execution c++

Tags: c++, templates, boost

So I have been with battling this for some time and this is also my first post here. I just wanted to know, if I passed in a container that was definitely a Forward Container, as defined in boost, how can I write code in a way that further checks to see if the code is either BackInsertionSequence or FrontInsertionSequence and executes depending on which type it is?

```
template <class SequentialContainer>
void MyClass<SequentialContainer>::SaySomething() {  
    BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::ForwardContainer<SequentialContainer>));  
    if (boost::BackInsertionSequence<SequentialContainer> == true) {  
        //do something  
    } else {  
        //say something else  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Look at tag dispatching or SFINAE.

Answer (score 2):

If you did an `if` check like you have there, both branches would have to be compiled regardless of the fact that only one branch would ever get executed for a particular type. That severely limits the usefulness of a simple `if` - you need a construct such that only one of the branches even compiles.

There are two common ways of doing this. Tag dispatch:

```
template <class SequentialContainer>
void MyClass<SequentialContainer>::SaySomething() {  
    SaySomething<SequentialContainer>(
        is_back_insertion_sequence<SequentialContainer>{}
    );
}

template <class SequentialContainer>
void SaySomething(std::true_type /* back insertion sequence */ ) { ... }

template <class SequentialContainer>
void SaySomething(std::false_type /* NOT back insertion sequence */ ) { ... }
```

And SFINAE:

```
template <class SequentialContainer>
typename std::enable_if<
    is_back_insertion_sequence<SequentialContainer>::value
>::type
SaySomething() {
    /* back insertion sequence */
}

template <class SequentialContainer>
typename std::enable_if<
    !is_back_insertion_sequence<SequentialContainer>::value
>::type
SaySomething() {
    /* NOT back insertion sequence */
}
```

There are advantages and disadvantages to both, but if it's just one flag that you're checking - it's primarily a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C++14 attempt to do the compile-time-branch purely within the function.  I don't know if it is a good idea.

```
template<
  template<class...>class Test, class Arg,
  class F1, class F2,
  class=std::enable_if_t<
    Test<Arg>{}
  >
>
std::result_of_t< F1(Arg) > branch( Arg&& arg, F1&& f1, F2&& f2 ) {
  return std::forward<F1>(f1)(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
};
template<
  template<class...>class Test, class Arg,
  class F1, class F2,
  class=std::enable_if_t<
    !Test<Arg>{}
  >
>
std::result_of_t< F2(Arg) > branch( Arg&& arg, F1&& f1, F2&& f2 ) {
  return std::forward<F2>(f2)(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
};
```

which is a compile time brancher.  We then do this:

```
template <class SequentialContainer>
void SaySomething() {
  branch<boost::BackInsertionSequence>( container,
  [&](auto&& container){ // true

  }, [&](auto&& container){ // false

  });
}
```

here we test `container` to determine if it is a `boost::BackInsertionSequence`.  If so, we run the first branch, and if not the second.

Under the standard, the code in each branch must have a valid specialization: which is why I passed the container in.  We can assume that the tested container has the property we want inside the code.

Comment: Haven't you already written a version with *named* operators to mimic *static if then else*? There's one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17198091/), but that's not the one I was thinking of..

Comment: @dyp Ya, possibly, but I don't remember everything I've written, but that rings a bell.  I might have just sketched it out; then again, strange details about it are showing up looking like memory, so maybe I wrote it out fully.  Name operators are just syntactic sugar anyhow.  The requirement that the auto lambda have a valid instantiation is a tricky one, and basically requires your test apply to the parameter passed to the lambda, which makes the syntax ugly even with named operators...